# How to solve $1/{4a^{-2}}$

Tags: exponentiation

Can i write $1/4a^{-2}$ as $4a^2$ ? Or is the right answer to do it like:

$$1/4a^{-2} = 1/4 \cdot 1/a^{-2} = 1/4 \cdot a^2 = a^2/4$$

In the problem there is no parenthesis around $4a$ but assuming there were parenthesis like $1/(4a)^{-2}$ would it be correct to write $4a^2$ ?

Comment: To the $\LaTeX$ifiers:  Please do not do stack the fractions in this post.  If you stack the fraction, the question will get lost.

Comment: @RossMillikan : I fear that calling MathJax $\text{“}\LaTeX\text{''}$ could lead to unpleasant consequences.  Someone could master MathJax and think they've mastered $\LaTeX$, and then encounter actual $\LaTeX$.  They'd get a considerable shock. $\qquad$

Comment: My guess, like Ross, is that $(1/4) a^{-2}$ is intended.  The other possibility would be $1/(4a^{-2})$.  Definitely not $1/(4a)^{-2}$.  Because it could be ambiguous, it should be written with parentheses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially, you should parse $1/4a^{-2}$ as $(1/4) \cdot a^{-2}$.  The exponential is evaluated first, then the multiplies and divides from left to right.  Certainly the $4$ belongs in the denominator.  The question is whether the $a^{-2}$ belongs in the denominator.  Given that the exponent is negative, I would think it likely that the author meant that.  On the other hand, if you see $1/4a^2$ it is likely that the author meant $1/(4a^2)$  instead of $a^2/4$ Parentheses are your friend.

Answer (score 0):

**If** you have $\dfrac{1}{(4a)^{-2}}$ then it would be $(4a)^2 = 16a^2$. Let me know if you have further questions..

Comment: Deep is answering the last line of the question.